# UnkownFormat error rails remote: true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my rails app that is in a popup. There is a javascript code that submits the form after 'Enter' is pressed.

```
<%= form_for(@chat, :remote => true, :html => {id: @sender_id}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, "data-mid" => @uniq_id %>
<% end %>
```

In the rails controller, I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js
end
```

I have create.js.erb file but I don't want to do anything in this file since all the rendering needed is done from another js file. The problem is I am getting an 'UnkownFormat' error even though all the data is correctly submitted to the database .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and found out my `application.js` was not requiring `jquery_ujs`. I added it to my `application.js` file:

```
//=require jquery
//=require jquery_ujs
```

Now `remote` links and forms work as expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I had already included that and other forms also work. It is only when I add the ':html => {id: @sender_id}' that id doesn't work. and I need the ID